# Why aren't monospace fonts almost never used for base font?

Tags: website-design, typography

I haven't come across any website that use monospace fonts as the base font for their websites. Why is that?

Does the website necessarily look bad when you use monospace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may look rather obsolete, probably that's why it is avoided, it was used rather heavily in the 90's along with animated GIFs and starred backgrounds and it didn't look very well.

Also it would be confusing since another monospaced: `Courier New` is used for preformatted text in `<pre>` blocks. So there is almost a convention that monospaced fonts are used for code and preformated text.

But I see no reason why not to use it, if you can find a good looking template, otherwise the above concerns might apply.

Comment: "it was used rather heavily in the 90's" - I don't think monospace text has ever been common place in website body copy?!

Comment: @w3d I agree that this is subjective experience since I didn't browsed all the Web, but if you ever knew geocities and other mainly personal sites some of them at least on my area of interest were using Courier New or other monospaced. 
I didn't used the right words with „rather heavily”,  I meant rather heavily compared to today standards

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is simply that most humans will find blocks of monospaced text harder to read than text that is proportionally spaced.